# Alter a unique index to set it deferrable in postgresq

Tags: postgresql, indexing, unique, postgresql-9.6

I need to alter a unique index which has already been created to set it deferrable. In postgres 9.6. Basically, i do something like:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;

CREATE TABLE test (id integer);

ALTER TABLE test ADD CONSTRAINT unique_id unique(id);

ALTER TABLE test ALTER CONSTRAINT unique_id DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

But i get

```
ERROR:  constraint "unique_id" of relation "test" is not a foreign key constraint
```

Documentation does not seem to mention that such action cannot be performed. What am i missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html)

> ALTER CONSTRAINT
>
> This form alters the attributes of a constraint that was previously created. Currently only foreign key constraints may be altered.

Instead you can:

```
ALTER TABLE test DROP CONSTRAINT unique_id;
ALTER TABLE test ADD CONSTRAINT unique_id unique(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```